# Error running a java program that uses log4j

Tags: java, windows, cmd, log4j

So i am trying to run a java file `launch.bat sdoc`(launch is a small script that have the jar used, but if necessary i can post it here) and i get this error.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:Users
ennasDesktopwebstorelogsvolume-server.sdoc.log
```

My config file is:

```
log4j.appender.dest.File=C:\Users\nennas\Desktop\webstore\logs\volume-server.sdoc.log
log4j.appender.dest.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, dest
log4j.appender.dest.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n
```

I already try some solution like changing \ to / and running as admin, the path is the absolute path. The folder exist but the strange thing is that in the error the url appears all together, by the way i am using windows 7. Ty for the help

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
log4j.appender.dest.File=C:\Users\nennas\Desktop\webstore\logs\volume-server.sdoc.log
```

by

```
log4j.appender.dest.File=C://Users//nennas//Desktop//webstore//logs//volume-server.sdoc.log
```

You can try also this

```
log4j.appender.dest.File=C:\\Users\\nennas\\Desktop\\webstore\\logs\\volume-server.sdoc.log
```

There is a lot of time since I don´t work with windows, but i remember similar problems with windows path and log4j

Comment: Thanks for your response but didn't work but something is strange when i run the java the path stay the same

Comment: Double-check you are not loading a different file that the one you are updating. Sometimes that kind of errors are the most difficult to see, I sometimes find myself into this :D